# Only start function when previous function has completed

Tags: java

I have 3 methods and they're being called from the front end. You can only call a function once you have called the previous function, but don't necessarily need to call all of them. So you may call either just f1, or f1->f2 or f1->f2->f3.

My problem is that on the front end you can click on a function, before the previous one has even stopped running. I need each function to finish before the next function starts running.

What I'm doing at the moment, which works, is pausing the execution until the end of the previous function, but I'd like for a nicer answer:

```
    f1 {
        ready1=false
        ...
        ready1=true }

    f2 {
        ready2=false
        while (!ready1) {Thread.sleep(250);}
        ...
        ready2=true }

    f3 {
        while (!ready2) {Thread.sleep(250);}
        ...
        }
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: you can to run next function using if..else..

Comment: Why are you working with parallel threads when you want sequential execution?

Comment: What about disabling/enabling the buttons?

Comment: the functions are being called from the front end; so you don't know when and even if they will be called
we're using a lot of repos, so I can't change the way these functions are called

Comment: I'm already enabling the 2nd button only if the 1st one has been clicked
but the functions are in the service repository, we also have a webservice repo in between and I'm just enabling-disabling the buttons on the 3rd repo with the front end. 
It would be harder to only enable the functions once the previous one has finished executing since it'd involve all 3 repos

Comment: are you calling these functions in sequence? I mean one after another with no code in between f1(); f2(); f3(): ?

Comment: What is it you're actually doing? What are these buttons and these sequences?

Comment: yes, but they might not necessarily all be called. And they don't care about the result of the previous function, but they should wait for it to end before starting execution

Comment: Can you give a bit better of an example for your code/java class? You could use a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to protect each method then you dont' have to use a Thread.sleep.

Comment: @Kayaman Uploading pictures to a database. There's a maximum of 3 pictures, so you may upload only one picture and then choose maybe a 2nd one and then maybe a 3rd one as well. Since I'm opening a connection to the DB in each function and then closing it once it executes the sql query, if I don't wait until the completion of one function and the next one already starts, it messed up the pictures and most times they were unable to upload

Comment: why don't you refuse the second upload request @ the back end if there is already a serving request ?

Comment: Shouldn't your web front end be able to let your server respond in that case, eg. don't enable button2 when it is click, enable it after the server has received the upload and responds somehow? Ill bet there are some callback type methods.

Comment: Yeah this sounds like a design issue. Seems like there's need for only one "function" instead of 3. If I've understood correctly, the question title should be "How can I upload 0-3 images to the server". It sounds like they don't even need to be sequential, but your previous code corrupted the data, so you decided to go this way. I'd suggest going back to your old code and fixing that, instead of trying to get this monster to work.

Comment: @Kayaman yes, because each has a different column in the db and uses a different query. Just adding images uses a lot of classes in each repo, I believe I did try to use the same methods for all 3. I used the same function I would run into the same problem: the fact that the function was already running would mess up the pictures.

Comment: @Zain Is there a way to do this in this class in which I already have the pictures and just sending them to the db?

Comment: @DOHere but that's the problem you should be solving. I.e. why did the images get messed up. Now you're trying to solve your "solution", which is not your original problem.

Comment: @matt That would have to involve more repos, and I'm just looking for an easy solution that I can do in this class. Was hoping there's a better way than the sleep method I'm using atm

Comment: @Kayaman I only wanted to change this class if there was a quick solution better than sleeping the thread, otherwise I'll just leave it like that

Comment: I think of using either .join() or CountDownLatch for cascading function execution

Comment: You asked for help too late and succumbed to the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There's no quick fix to pretty up your solution, so do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a web framework, so maybe include the framework, and it will have some built in tools. One example is to use the built in java tools.

```
class NoLookingBack{
    CountDownLatch latchB = new CountDownLatch(1);


    public void methodA(){
      //do work.
      latchB.countDown();
    }

    public void methodB(){
        try{
            latchB.await();
        } catch(InterruptException e){
            //do something or declare this method throws.
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this shows how more methods could be included by adding more latches when necessary.

Your example is flawed, and so is this solution. What if methodA fails,  then methodB will block forever. The latch gives you the power to use a timeout value, then you can use a response that indicates a failure.

Comment: The sleep is conditioned to go for a max of 2 seconds only, anyway, but even if the upload fails the function will still end. And the success or failure of the previous function doesn't matter to the next one
But will try your solution

Comment: @DOHere it is pretty much the same thing, except for instead of sleep, it uses `.await`. Both of these solutions seem to violate a certain principle of statelessness for http requests. You don't want to rely on the same `NoLookingBack` class being used to handle your requests. This solution will not scale, and depending on the framework, will not work. You really should include the framework used.

Comment: It's a bigger application with service, webservice and front end. The functions I mentioned are in the DAO class in the service part of the application. I know this kind of solution is not optimal, but this is an old java app and it's not a priority

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the state of an *instance of your class* to see if the method has been called. You should be querying the DAO to see if the data is there. If it isn't either wait, and check again and eventually timeout with an error response. I understand not wanting to invest too much time in a legacy product though. So good luck.